# I am curious about the time complexity

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am curious about the complexity of:-

1. a function that multiply input by 5 (n*5)
2. a function that add 5 to the input (n+5)
3. 

```
def func(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 1 
    return func(n-1) + func(n-2) + func(n-3)
```

in (3) is the time complexity o(3**n)?

Comment: 1. O(1) , 2. O(1)

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar Unlike 3., those might reasonably get called with arbitrarily large numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough, `O(func(n))` is just `func(n)`.  Why?  The only real think your code can do is add 1.  So whatever result it go, it got there by calling itself some multiple of `func(n)` times.

The same logic applies to the Fibonacii function.  The naive implementation has time `O(fib(n))`

Comment: What do you mean with `O(func(n))`?

Comment: Your function is roughly its own complexity.  It will take roughly O(`func(n)`) time to calculate `func(n)`, where `func(n)` is the function you're defining above.

Comment: I think you mean T(n) instead of O(func(n)) then. Writing "O(func(n)) is just func(n)" is at least confusing if not wrong (I'd say it's wrong). Not mine, btw.

Comment: Sorry.  I don't understand.  What is T?

Comment: Short name for running time, you can see "T(n)" used many times on Wikipedia's [Time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) page. What did *you* mean with "O" when you wrote "O(func(n))"? It seems like you meant it as "running time of func(n)", but that's not what it means.